# text mining: read text files in Python

Tags: python

When I use R, I can read many text documents which are contained in a file folder for one time.
However, I just started to learn Python. When I use command: `file = open('c:/txt/Romney', 'r')`,trying to open all text files contained in that Romney folder, I found out I have to read inside text files one by one, I cannot read all for one time just like I do in R. Any suggestion?

Comment: What do you mean by "all at once"? Do you want to concatenate them? Or iterate over them one-by-one?

Comment: I'm curious how R does it. That behavior sounds like R trying to guess what you might want to do

Comment: Posting the R code you are trying to emulate/duplicate in Python would be helpful.

Answer (score 5):

In a language like Python, you'll need to use a `for` loop to read the contents of each file, one at a time.

(Related: [How to list all files of a directory in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3207973/2338327))

```
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join

path = "C:/txt/Romney"
files = [ f for f in listdir(path) if isfile(join(path,f)) ]

for file in files:
    with open file as f:
        text = f.read()
        do_something_with(text)
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Dave Yarwood's answer, if what you actually wanted to do was concatenate the files, you could do it with:

```
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
from itertools import chain

path = "C:/txt/Romney"
files = [open(f) for f in listdir(path) if isfile(join(path,f))]

for line in chain(*files):
    do_something_with(line)
```

(just for fun, because I've never used `itertools.chain` to string together files before)

Comment: Shouldn't you then do `for file in files: file.close()`?

Comment: And wouldn't it be `[f.open() for f in ...` ?

Comment: @DaveYarwood The file is automatically closed when the object gets garbage collected. And `listdir` just returns a list of strings, not file handles. Strings don't have an `open` method.